# How to make two horizontally aligned tables?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Every time I create a HTML table, it starts on a new paragraph. Is it possible to override this behaviour, so that I have two tables on the same row?

I'm using also CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always found it easier to just create a table that contains the 2 tables if i want them to always be on same row.

```
    <table>
       <tr>
         <td>
           <table id="table1">
             <tr>
               <td></td>
             </tr>
           </table>
         </td>
         <td>
           <table id="table2">
             <tr>
               <td></td>
             </tr>
           </table>
         </td>
       </tr>
     </table>
```

styling works too though.

Comment: this is the correct solution although `display:inline` will work too.

Comment: Then you're using table elements when you could be using styling, which is generally frowned upon. See [Why not use tables for layout in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html)

Comment: Maybe this is for an email template, where tables is all you can use for layout.

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to style them, `display: inline;` or float both the tables.

Answer (score 0):

set `display: inline-block;` for each table.

online demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bitsmix/s7Bec/

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/55cc077/p9p12m2z/)

If you need the horizontally aligned tables to fill 100% width, you need:
`display:inline-table; and float:left;`